How do I prevent unnecessary re-render of the other child component?
I am building a simple login page for my app and the structure of it looks like this:
<SignIn />
  --> <SignInFormComponent />
  --> <NeedHelpComponent />

SigInFormComponent has 2 input boxes.  1 for email and 1 for password and a "Continue" button.
NeedHelpComponent is a collapsible link for password reset.
So if I hit "Continue" to submit login info, only its parent component, SignIn and SignInFormComponent are re-rendered, which is fine because I want to show the login error message in SignIn component.
However, if I hide/show the password reset link in NeedHelpComponent, all 3 components are re-rendered.  So my question is how do I prevent SignIn and SignInFormComponent from re-rendering?
export default function SignIn() {
  const [loginErrMessage, setShowLoginErrMessage] = useState(null);
  const [showHelp, setShowHelp] = useState(false);

  const handleShowHideHelp = () => {
    showHelp ? setShowHelp(false) : setShowHelp(true);
  };
  const memoHandleShowHideHelp = useCallback(handleShowHideHelp, [showHelp]);

  const handleLoginError = (loginError) => setShowLoginErrMessage(loginError);
  const memoHandleLoginError = useCallback(handleLoginError, [loginErrMessage]);

  return (
    <div className="container auth-container text-center ps-sm-7 pe-sm-7 ps-xl-15 pe-xl-15">
      <h1 className="fs-2 custom-font-family-teko custom-color-darkpurple">
        <BrandComponent customWidth={10} customHeight={10} />
      </h1>

      {loginErrMessage ? (
        <p className="custom-background-color-red custom-color-antiquewhite fs-7">
          {loginErrMessage}
        </p>
      ) : (
        <></>
      )}

      <div className="border border-secondary-subtle border-1 rounded-2 text-start pt-3 pb-3">
        <h2 className="ms-5 fw-bolder">Sign in</h2>

        <SignInFormComponent loginErrMessage={loginErrMessage} handleLoginError={memoHandleLoginError} />

        <NeedHelpComponent showHelp={showHelp} handleShowHideHelp={memoHandleShowHideHelp} />

        <div className="text-center mt-3">
          <p>---------- New to GymBro? ----------</p>
          <div className="mt-3">
            <Link to="/register">
              <button className="custom-background-color-antiquewhite fw-medium fs-7 p-1 ps-3 pe-3 border border-light rounded-1">
                Create your GymBro account
              </button>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <TrademarkComponent />
    </div>
  );
}

const SignInFormComponent = ({ handleLoginError }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const emailRef = useRef(null);
  const passwordRef = useRef(null);

  const [emailInput, setEmailInput] = useState({
    style: validStyle,
    errMessage: null,
  });
  const [passwordInput, setPasswordInput] = useState({
    style: validStyle,
    errMessage: null,
  });

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (emailRef.current.value && passwordRef.current.value) {
      setEmailInput({ style: validStyle, errMessage: null });
      setPasswordInput({ style: validStyle, errMessage: null });

      const signInServerResponse = await fetch("/users/sign-in", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: emailRef.current.value,
          password: passwordRef.current.value,
        }),
      });

      switch (signInServerResponse.status) {
        case 201:
          return navigate("/");
        case 400:
          handleLoginError(AppMessageConfig.auth["not-verified"]);
          break;
        case 401:
        case 404:
          handleLoginError(AppMessageConfig.auth["not-match"]);
          break;
        case 500:
          handleLoginError(AppMessageConfig.server.generic);
          break;
        default:
          return;
      }
    } else {
      handleLoginError(null); // remove login error message

      // manipulate styling of each input box for better user experience
      const inputRefs = [emailRef, passwordRef];

      for (const inputRef of inputRefs) {
        switch (inputRef.current.id) {
          case "email":
            if (inputRef.current.value === "") {
              setEmailInput({
                style: invalidStyle,
                errMessage: AppMessageConfig.auth.email,
              });
            } else {
              if (emailInput.style === invalidStyle) {
                setEmailInput({ style: validStyle, errMessage: null });
              }
            }

            break;
          case "password":
            if (inputRef.current.value === "") {
              setPasswordInput({
                style: invalidStyle,
                errMessage: AppMessageConfig.auth.password,
              });
            } else {
              if (passwordInput.style === invalidStyle) {
                setPasswordInput({ style: validStyle, errMessage: null });
              }
            }

            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="ps-5 pe-5">
        <label htmlFor="email" className="form-label fw-medium fs-13">
          Email
        </label>

        <input
          type="email"
          className={emailInput.style}
          id="email"
          name="email"
          ref={emailRef}
        />

        {emailInput.errMessage ? (
          <p className="fs-7 custom-color-red ms-1">{emailInput.errMessage}</p>
        ) : (
          <></>
        )}
      </div>

      <div className="ps-5 pe-5 mt-2">
        <label htmlFor="password" className="form-label fw-medium fs-13">
          Password
        </label>

        <input
          type="password"
          className={passwordInput.style}
          id="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="At least any 6 characters"
          ref={passwordRef}
        />

        {passwordInput.errMessage ? (
          <p className="fs-7 custom-color-red ms-1">
            {passwordInput.errMessage}
          </p>
        ) : (
          <></>
        )}
      </div>

      <div className="ps-5 pe-5 mt-3 text-center">
        <button className="btn custom-background-color-darkpurple custom-color-antiquewhite custom-font-family-teko fw-bolder custom-width-92">
          Continue
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default React.memo(SignInFormComponent);

const NeedHelpComponent = ({ showHelp, handleShowHideHelp }) => {
    console.log("Need Help Component re-renders...");

    return (
        <div className="ps-5 mt-3">
        {showHelp ? (
          <CaretDownFill size={15} color="#3E0957" />
        ) : (
          <CaretRightFill size={15} color="#3E0957" />
        )}
        &nbsp;
        <Link className="fs-11" onClick={handleShowHideHelp}>
          Need help?
        </Link>
        {showHelp ? (
          <div>
            <Link className="fs-11 ps-4" to="/forgotpassword">
              Forgot your password
            </Link>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <></>
        )}
      </div>
    )
}

export default React.memo(NeedHelpComponent)

I tried to useCallback() to call handleLoginError() only if loginErrMessage changes but doesn't seem to work.

To understand the problem first, the SignIn component is rendering because when you click on the "Need help" button the handleShowHideHelp is called in the parent and it changes it's state. The state change leads to a component re-render along with all of it's children including the SignInFormComponent unless you memoize the props for the SignInFormComponent properly.
Anyways, to solve your problem all you need to do is to put all the logic for the help condition from SignIn component into the NeedHelpComponent since it's the only component that uses those things.
So you should delete showHelp state, handleShowHideHelp and memoHandleShowHideHelp from the SignIn component and now the NeedHelpComponent component can look something like this:


const NeedHelpComponent = (/* remove the props */) => {
    const [showHelp, setShowHelp] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div className="ps-5 mt-3">
        {showHelp ? (
          <CaretDownFill size={15} color="#3E0957" />
        ) : (
          <CaretRightFill size={15} color="#3E0957" />
        )}
        &nbsp;
        <Link className="fs-11" onClick={() => setShowHelp((prevState) => !prevState)}>
          Need help?
        </Link>
        {showHelp ? (
          <div>
            <Link className="fs-11 ps-4" to="/forgotpassword">
              Forgot your password
            </Link>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <></>
        )}
      </div>
    )
}

export default React.memo(NeedHelpComponent)






What's the use of React.memo in NeedHelpComponent here?  From what I understand, using memo will cause React to skip rendering a component if its props have not changed.  However you're not passing any props to NeedHelpComponent


SignInFormComponent still re-renders.  What's happening here?



You are right, the memo doesn't do anything here, it was just copied from your code. I just wanted to demonstrate how you should put the states from the parent into the child component didn't take a look at the rest of the code that is left for you to polish. But then something is missing, if by clicking need help here in this setup you get the SignInFormComponent re-rendered then you didn't provide all the information as now the NeedHelpComponent can't affect any state from the SignIn nor the SignInFormComponent causing them to re-render.
